# Available methods WebApi expect key to communicate. (Authorization)

Tags: soapui

I am testing a WebApi that expects key provided after reporting the credentials "Login", "Password".
To consume and get to test my Api I need to inform this key in all methods, there are some
Way to inform this authorization in the ownership of the other methods, and after validating the key start my test case. Without this key the system returns the expired user message.

Comment: Unclear question. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the senario:
A system that adds, edits and deletes users, to access these functions you need to log in with an "Administrator" user.
So my api would have a method log, edit, delete and add.

To test my api depends on an "Authorization" key that is informed after logging into the system, the other methods: add, edit and delete depends on this "Authorization" key to communicate with my api and perform the input and output actions.

Is there any way to pass this "Authorization" key on the test case properties, or script that you do not have to manually pass.

I hope it has been clearer.